# SQL db lookup on each row in Excel

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, excel

I have created a webpage where employees can upload an Excel xlsx document for processing and have the same document returned with certain key cells filled in if requirements are met.  It works, but I am not pleased with the speed at which it runs.  It takes a couple of minutes to get through 2,500 rows.

It runs like this:
User uploads document -> 
Server-side opens the excel document and goes row by row -> 
If column 31 of current row != 10 then connect to SQL and perform query based on column 5. -> 
Results from query go into that row column 35. -> 
Next row. Rinse and repeat. -> 
On complete, return file to user.

While this works, it is also rather slow.  Does anyone have any thoughts on better ways to approach this?

```
 For n = 2 To excelWorkSheet.Rows.Count

            Dim thing As String = excelWorkSheet.Cells(n, 5).Value
            'only until empty row 
            If excelWorkSheet.Cells(n, 5).Value = "" Then
                Exit For
            End If


            If excelWorkSheet.Cells(n, 31).Value <> "10" Then
                strSQL = "EXEC sp_Lookup_Type " & thing
                cmd.CommandText = strSQL
                cmd.Connection = cn
                rdrSQL = cmd.ExecuteReader()


                While rdrSQL.Read()
                    If Not IsDBNull(rdrSQL("TYPE")) Then
                        excelWorkSheet.Cells(n, 35).Value = rdrSQL("TYPE")
                    Else
                        excelWorkSheet.Cells(n, 35).Value = "NO DATA"
                    End If
                End While

                cmd.Dispose()
                rdrSQL.Close()
            End If
        Next

        cn.Close()
```

Comment: Are you opening the workbook and then modifying it or doing it in the background?

Comment: I am opening the file as an microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheet, then iterating through each row.  Each row is modified as I iterate through and then saved at the end.  This is all happening on the server - the client is simply shown a "Now Processing" page.

Comment: David has the best approach but a simple way to improve speed is to turn off screenupdating=false at the beginning of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My goal would be to reduce the number of SQL calls.

**Option #1:** If the number of items in your lookup table is small enough...

- Download all of the lookup table once at the beginning of your loop
- Within the loop, check this local copy of the database table instead of going to the database each time.

**Option #2:** If you can't cache all of the items up front...

- Loop through your spreadsheet once and gather a list of items to lookup.
- Make a single call to the database, sending all of the items at once.
- The database returns a small list of values that are needed.
- Use the small list as your database cache and follow the steps in "Option #1"

Comment: I wound up using Option 2 and it shaved a few minutes off of the processing time.  I wound up using a System.Data.Datatable and pre-populated that with the row number and lookup key I would later need.  I then passed the data table to a SQL stored procedure.  The results were then parsed and placed back into the excel table based on the row number.